# Button Doesn't Work If Created Using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have this kind of structure

```
<button ng-click="something(1)">click!</button>
<div id="place"></div>
```

something() works in this situation, but if I try to make another button with innerHTML on a js code

```
   str="<button ng-click=\"something(2)\">click 2!</button>"
   document.getElementById("place").innerHTML = str;
```

thrn the 2nd button, the one created by innerHTML, apears normal, but doesn't call the function something() when clicked

Is there a nother way to add the button? the buttons should be generated proceduraly as the page runs

Thank you very much!

Comment: what is "ng-click"? I guess this is some sort of framework you are using, and it will "preload" all the possible listeners during DOM-Construction - hence, if you add a button via plain HTML later, it's unknown...

Using Vanilla "onclick" this would work...

Comment: Yep, because this is not at all how AngularJS/Angular/Vue/React work... `getElementById` is a nonsense in an Angular app, and so is `.innerHTML`.

Comment: You are adding elements in a non-angular way so angular wont process it like the others and hook the ng-click properly

Comment: @dognose `ng-click` is Angular 1 aka AngularJS, which Angular 2 deprecated back in 2016

Comment: Ok, so my guess was right :) Then ofc. Buttons need to be added in the "angular" way ;)

Answer (score -1):

```js
<script>
        let btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.innerText = "click2"
        // class
        btn.classList = [];
        // on click function
        btn.onclick = () => {

        }
        document.getElementById("place").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("place").appendChild(btn)
    </script>
```